# I look for method or framework that can tell the percentage of reading pdf

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development. I want to build an application that has one feature for a "reading now" screen. In that screen I want to show the percentage of a book that I've read, but I can't find any solution on the internet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would to access the `currentPage` instance property if you are using `PDFKit` and `PDF View`, which are already built-in since iOS 11. See more at [Apple's Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/1504963-currentpage)

When a user flips to another page in the PDF, you can store the `currentPage`, which can be later manipulated to calculate your reading progress for example.

Comment: @moji Hey just a reminder, if it worked please accept the answer.